# Bypass the ordering inside the Meta class

Tags: django

I have two models:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    course_member = models.ForeignKey(CourseMember, on_delete=models.CASCADE

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'member'
        ordering = ['-id']

class CourseMember(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

When I try running to get a count for members that have course_member.

```
Member.objects.values('course_member').aggregate(Count('id'))
```

I keep getting the wrong data. It seems that instead of grouping by course_member, it keeps grouping by member_id, and I queryset with individual results.

The Django docs warn about this issue, [see link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by).

I'm trying to see if there is a solution to bypass this issue instead of just waiting for Django 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of `Member`s *per* `CourseMember`s, I suggest that you work the other way around:

```
from django.db.models import Count

CourseMember.objects.annotate(
    nmember=Count('member')
)
```

This will return the set of `CourseMember`s, but where every `CourseMember` has an extra attribute `nmember` that stores the number of related `Member` objects.

You can get the queryset in your question working with:

```
Member.objects.values(
    'course_member'
).annotate(
    n=Count('id')
).order_by('course_member')
```

The `.order_by` is of importance here as well, since otherwise, it will indeed not properly "group" the data.

But the above has two potential problems:

1. it will *not* include `CourseMember`s that have no `CourseMember`s; and
2. here you get a `QuerySet` of dictionaries, that is not that "rich" as a `QuerySet` of `CourseMember`s, since on the `CourseMember`s, you can define all sorts of extra behavior, properties, etc.

Comment: Adding the order_by at the end will override the ordering setting inside the Meta class. Thank you!